# How to import data from Cassandra into Hadoop File System

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, bigdata

I would like to know how to import data from Cassandra into Hadoop File System and how can this be done on an ongoing basis regularly (i.e as an when there is a change in the Cassandra DB or new data is inserted into Cassandra how can we detect the change and migrate the data into HDFS(Hadoop File System)?.

Answer (score 1):

you have multiple options to do that. you can write sequential programs or mapreduce jobs or pig etc. for the automation, you again have several options. you can have a cron that'll do that for you or if you want your workflow to be more sophisticated, you can use Oozie(A workflow engine) that'll schedule your jobs on whatever criteria you want.
HTH